# Right way to switch between tabs and change layout of the application?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, fragment

I'm currently developing an application that has a tab bar, and 3
different views: the first is a master-detail, the second one a
gallery, the third is a simple webview.

I was using the TabActivity, but since Android 3.0, this class is
deprecated and Android reference
suggests to use Fragments.

I switched then to an ActionBar, with Tabs and Action
Items. Inseide the first tab item I have a layout with 2 fragments (my
master-detail view). When I switch through tabs I want that my layout
change as I described above, so I thought to hide the left fragment
(the master listview) and work only in the detail fragment.. but with
this solution I have only one main activity with a lot of fragments
attached to it, and for each fragment displayed I need to modify the
Action Item shown and handle different actions in
OnOptionItemSelected.

Is this a good way to implement this kind of
application or should I consider different solutions?

Comment: Whether or not you should use the TabActivity is depending on which devices you are wanting to target for your app. Just because the TabActivity has been deprecated doesn't mean that the new devices won't run it. In fact, they still do. But if you are looking at targeting the majority of the devices on the market, then you are not going to want to do Fragments and stick with the TabActivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a single fragment container where the fragments are replaced depending on the tab selected.

One activity and multiple fragments is the right approach.

Comment: Just be careful, fragments are only supported on Android 11 and higher. And according to the Android website, that is only about 1/6 of the current market of phones out there. Most running Android 9 - 10.

Comment: @Wizetux, no that's not true. They're only supported directly by the API in 11+, but the compatibility library brings support all the way back to v4.

Comment: Ah, so you have to ship with the static library in your application in order to get this to work on older devices.

Comment: I am programming a specific app only for tablets...so no problem for Android Version!